# MongoDB Aggregate Multiple grouping based on time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to show the top customers in the last 24 hours and last 12 hours using a single query.
We save the total orders of the customer in the db every hour.
The raw data are something like the below, but I changed the data for confidentiality:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("64c8de6e10f1e5f6958033d7"),
    "address": "nowhere",
    "city": "NY",
    "name": "ABD",
    "count": NumberInt(19),
    "timestamp": ISODate("2023-08-01T05:30:42.956Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("64c8de6e10f1e5f6958033d6"),
    "address": "somewhere",
    "city": "NY",
    "name": "WBE",
    "count": NumberInt(4),
    "timestamp": ISODate("2023-08-01T05:29:02.956Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("64c8de6e10f1e5f6958033da"),
    "address": "somewhere",
    "city": "NY",
    "name": "WBE",
    "count": NumberInt(18),
    "timestamp": ISODate("2023-08-01T08:30:42.956Z")
  }
  ...
]
```

The result I was trying to go for was something like:

```
{
  last12Hours: [{ name: "WBE", city:"NY", count: "18" }, {name: "ABD", city:"NY", count: "12"}],
  last24Hours: [{ name: "WBE", city:"NY", count: "30" }, {name: "ABD", city:"NY", count: "20"}],
}
```

This is simple if I run two queries where I change the timestamp match to 12 hours before and 24 hours before:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      timestamp: {
        $gte: ISODate("2023-08-01T03:36:38.059Z")
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      count: {
        $sum: "$count"
      },
     city: { $first: "$city"}
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      count: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 5,
    
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id",
      city: "$city",
      count: 1,
    },
  },
])
```

I also tried something that has to do with intervals but that was a disaster of a query and didn't work as expected.

I appreciate hints, I'm not supposedly asking for anyone to just solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$facet` is not using indexes, you may want to use it as late as possible in your pipeline. Another option, following @YongShun, is to `$match` and `$group` before the `$facet` using `$cond`. This will allow you to use the index on these stages, and enter the `$facet` stage with less documents:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {timestamp: {$gte: /* Last 24 hours timestamp */}}},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$name", 
      count24: {$sum: "$count"},
      count12: {$sum: {$cond: [
            {$gte: ["$timestamp",/* Last 12 hours timestamp */]},
            "$count",
            0
      ]}},
      city: {$first: "$city"}
  }},
  {$facet: {
      last24Hours: [
        {$sort: {count24: -1}},
        {$limit: 5},
        {$project: {_id: 0, name: "$_id", city: 1, count: "$count24"}}
      ],
      last12Hours: [
        {$sort: {count12: -1}},
        {$limit: 5},
        {$match: {count12: {$ne: 0}}},
        {$project: {_id: 0, name: "$_id", city: 1, count: "$count12"}}
      ]
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lvrpL5KbKgf)

Comment: Works well and its using the index as I need it! Perfect! Thank you. Learned something today about utilizing the $cond with the parent match

Answer (score 2):

For your scenario, you need the [`$facet`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage to execute multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage and result in a single document.

Unsure what is your `last12HoursTimestamp` and `last24HoursTimestamp`, your query should be as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "last12Hours": [
        {
          $match: {
            timestamp: {
              $gte: /* Last 12 hours timestamp */
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            count: {
              $sum: "$count"
            },
            city: {
              $first: "$city"
            }
          },
          
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            count: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 5
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: "$_id",
            city: "$city",
            count: 1,
            
          }
        }
      ],
      "last24Hours": [
        {
          $match: {
            timestamp: {
              $gte: /* Last 24 hours timestamp */
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            count: {
              $sum: "$count"
            },
            city: {
              $first: "$city"
            }
          },
          
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            count: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 5
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: "$_id",
            city: "$city",
            count: 1,
            
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9NqmhbeHo28)

**Bonus:** Besides passing the timestamp, you may use the MongoDB operator & function to calculate the timestamps for the last 12 & 24 hours as well.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      last12HoursTimestamp: {
        "$dateSubtract": {
          "startDate": "$$NOW",
          "unit": "hour",
          "amount": 12
        }
      },
      last24HoursTimestamp: {
        "$dateSubtract": {
          "startDate": "$$NOW",
          "unit": "hour",
          "amount": 24
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "last12Hours": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $gte: [
                "$timestamp",
                "$last12HoursTimestamp"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            count: {
              $sum: "$count"
            },
            city: {
              $first: "$city"
            }
          },
          
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            count: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 5
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: "$_id",
            city: "$city",
            count: 1,
            
          }
        }
      ],
      "last24Hours": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $gte: [
                "$timestamp",
                "$last24HoursTimestamp"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            count: {
              $sum: "$count"
            },
            city: {
              $first: "$city"
            }
          },
          
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            count: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 5
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: "$_id",
            city: "$city",
            count: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I often learn from your answers, please checkout mine this time, I think you'll like it

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll be picking nimrod's answer though because of the indexing utilization.
Thanks for teaching me about the facet